# Node JS Agenda scheduler - Missing scheduled tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduler

Am Using Agenda plugin as Scheduler (along with express)

This is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var Agenda = require('agenda');


var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: 'localhost:27017/express'}});
var app= express();

app.get('/notify', function(req,res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    var message = req.param('message');
    agenda.now('send reminder', {data:message});    

    res.send(message);  
});

    agenda.define('send reminder', function(job,done){
        console.log(job.attrs.data.data);
    });


agenda.start();
app.listen(80);
```

These are the problems am facing

- Not all messages are getting printed
- Some times the message is getting printed more than once.
- After 10 calls (approx), the scheduler stops forever
- There is atleast a 2 second delay in invoking the scheduled

Some light would be appretiated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in my code was , I forgot to call done() method

It should be either

```
agenda.define('send reminder', function(job,done){
        console.log(job.attrs.data.data);
done();

    });
```

or

```
agenda.define('send reminder', function(job){
        console.log(job.attrs.data.data);
    });
```

Comment: Note that if you code is synchronous you can omit the `done` parameter https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda#definejobname-options-fn

Answer (score 3):

I set up a test with Agenda as follows

```
var agenda = new Agenda();
agenda.database(config.db.host + ':' + config.db.port + '/' + config.db.name, 'jobs')
var i = 0;
agenda.define('some job', function(job) {
i++;
console.log( i+ " Run at " + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
});
agenda.every('10 seconds', 'some job');
agenda.start();
```

Output is as follows -

> 1 Run at 56:59
>
> 2 Run at 57:13
>
> 3 Run at 57:28
>
> 4 Run at 57:43
>
> 5 Run at 57:58
>
> 6 Run at 58:13
>
> and so on...

I left the job running for 3 hrs and I still see it running. I haven't seen any of your first three observations. I do see a delay of ~5s for each run as you can see by the second print. This could be because of mongo latency due to the remote database I am hitting and / or due to log printing delay. I have used Agenda before and I don't think you should use it if you need to execute your job at a precision of seconds.

As an aside, why would you use a scheduler for a now event, won't you just use console.log() when you need to log? If you need to do something else async, isn't it a simple call.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
I used the example given in Agenda website which schedules a job every 3 minutes. Unfortunately, that did not work, as I dont see the jobs getting executed every 3 minutes. And coming to Schedule now, my designed my solution such that, "Schedule everything", so that I can even log whats happening. I may schedule things later too..

Comment: how to run many such scheduled jobs with each job having unique id and then stop a specific job on button click

Comment: @prc I tried following your approach and this script does not seems to work. It results in errors like `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOneAndUpdate' of undefined`. Did you faced the same or something else your can suggest?